# How should we deal with general anime and manga questions that doesn't really fit in manga- or anime-production tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently we had a [question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4573/how-do-i-read-manga-with-multiple-panes) that didn't really feel like it falls under [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production), so I provisionally created a [general-manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-manga) tag.

Should we have a general tag (either an all inclusive one or or separate ones for anime and manga) for miscellaneous questions that don't fall under either [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production) and [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production)?

Is there a better way we can handle this? Or are we just chasing a figurative unicorn here?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a fan of [general-manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-manga). It has most of the problems that [manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) would have had (hence why it's blacklisted), namely that it would be incorrectly applied frequently and too broad. It seems to subsume all other manga-specific tags, such as [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production), at least in principle. Furthermore, I literally can't imagine any other questions which would be in [general-manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-manga) that are not already covered by one or more existing tags. Rather, when questions like this come up, we should find more specific tags for them.

In my view, a better tag for this question would be a fairly specific tag for this sort of question, namely [panel-arrangement](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/panel-arrangement) or something similar. This would include all questions asking about the flow of a specific page of manga, and it could be useful for future askers in a relatively small number of cases. For example, I still get confused occasionally when reading shoujo manga, as (for whatever reason) it often has much more complicated arrangements than most other genres. There's quite a bit more to how panels are arranged than just "read left-to-right" so I think the tag makes sense, though it will probably be a low-volume tag.

Finally, regarding this particular question, I think it should be edited to be more descriptive. The OP isn't really looking for the "general rule" of what the right order to read the panels is. The general rule, insofar as one exists, is to read right-to-left, and the OP already knew this. There are exceptions to that rule, which is why [panel-arrangement](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/panel-arrangement) isn't totally trivial, but that's the only simple "general rule" which exists. What the OP really wants to know is how he should read this particular page of manga and why it is not in the usual arrangement. He may have been looking for a rule that can be applied in all such cases, but with the number of exceptions and special cases such a question is probably closeable as "too broad". Making it specific to this particular page of the Naruto manga in both the title and question body would make the question more objectively answerable, avoid spoilers for future viewers, and pave the way for occasional future questions in the same vein about different confusing pages.

So in summary, the changes I suggest (both for this question and in terms of [general-manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-manga)) are:

- Keep [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto) on the question
- Add [panel-arrangement](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/panel-arrangement) to this question
- Remove [general-manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-manga) from this and any other questions
- Make the question title and body specific to this page of manga

Comment: `panel-arrangement` seems like a very niche tag, would there be any other cases would there would be some merit to using this tag?

Comment: @Krazer As I said, I've had situations while reading manga where I'm not exactly sure what's going on in a particular scene, so I can imagine using it myself occasionally. I tried to come up with something broader which would cover all questions regarding what is happening in a particular manga scene, but everything I could come up with either seemed too broad or to invite undesirable questions like "Where can I read manga X?". If you have a better suggestion then feel free to give it, as I agree [panel-arrangement] is a bit specific; I just couldn't come up with anything better.

Comment: As a note, in case anyone doesn't believe that panel arrangements can get pretty complicated, here's [an example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sVa8t.png) from the shoujo manga Oniisama e.... There are probably better examples if you look, but this was one of the first pages I saw and it's already not entirely clear to me what the "right" order is to read the panels in, at least at first glance. I do agree that no matter what [panel-arrangement] will be somewhat a niche tag, but this probably won't be the only question and at any rate a niche tag doesn't necessarily seem like a problem.

Comment: My vote is cast on this one. However narrow the subject, [tag:panel-arrangement] seems best fit for this kind of question.

Answer (score 2):

I think a [general-manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-manga) would be considered a meta-tag per: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

> The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.).
>
> Meta-tags are actually a subset of a larger problem that I usually call dependent tags. These are tags that don’t say anything by themselves – you can’t tell what the question is about unless they’re paired with some other tag (or several of them). These tags are a problem because people don’t realize this and will often use that as the question’s only tag.

I propose [manga-reading](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-reading) as it describes the content of the question.

Comment: [tag:manga-consumption] to me seems like questions about things like manga sales (e.g. [this question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4503/24)), not how to read manga. I might suggest the term [tag:manga-reading] instead, which is a bit broader than the suggestion in my answer [tag:panel-arrangement] but still specific enough. The only issue with that name is that it almost invites questions like "where can I read manga X online for free" which we definitely don't want.

Comment: @LoganM I can see that, I agree that manga-reading is better, I'll edit my post (consumption vs production - producer-consumer, was how i came up with the tag, comes from my programming background i guess). I don't think the tag itself will invite question like "where can i read" though, since in my experience, tags are something you add after writing a question.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should take the simplest route:

**Tag the question with the series (or author) it's from (or by).**

In this case, [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto) or [masashi-kishimoto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masashi-kishimoto).

Even if we have questions about how to read certain panels on pages, it's usually localized to the just that series or author. Even if we have questions about how to read certain panels on pages, it's usually localized to the just that series or author, rarely does an author deviate from a normal style. Questions about panel layout should stay consistent with in a series...

Questions about why the paneling in two (or more) series differ can probably fall under [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production), but questions about the panel arrangement of a certain series, should go under fall under the series itself.

Just like how was can examine/ask questions the artistic style of an anime, with the series/author (probably director in this case) tag, I think asking about the panel arrangement falls under the same category.